# Between two, or a flame at night

Tags: riddle, word

> Many go to me to meet,
>   You can get to me without your feet;
>   A candle or a lamp at night,
>   To use I must at first ignite;
>   With me you’ll see,
>   Some at first sight;
>   A burning fire of love’s desire
>   Between two, or a flame at night.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be the word:

> match?

Many go to me to meet

You can get to me without your feet:

> Match.com, a dating website which you can get to using only your fingers. (thanks @Aggiekidd)

A candle or a lamp at night

To use at first I must ignite

> To light a candle or a lamp, you first need to strike a match

With me you'll see

Some at first sight

> Something to do with matches made in heaven and love at first sight?

A burning fire of love's desire

Between two or a flame at night

> Again, match can mean both "a flaming stick" or a "pair" even a pair of people in love.

Comment: The word you have is the correct answer, but there is a missing piece that will iron out the questions you have

Comment: There is match.com, an online dating website that may be relevant.

Comment: @AggieKidd bingo